# Accessing a value of a class's variable from another - objective-c

Tags: ios, properties

This is probably a silly question but I'm having a hard time trying to solve it. The thing is that a have a class that implements a counter and at the end of it procedures it calls a view controlled by another class. What I'd like to do is access the value of the counter of the first class from the second one. I defined the counter as a property and tried to access it from the other class but I always get its value as 0. Can anyone help me out?

thanks.

What i have is this:

*Class1.h*

```
@interface Class1 : CCLayerColor <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    int movesCounter;
}
@property int movesCounter;

@end
```

*Class1.m*

```
@implementation Class1
@synthesize movesCounter;

//At this point the counter gets incremented and NSLogging its value correctly

@end
```

*Class2.m*

```
#import Class1.h    

@implementation GameOverLayer


-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
       Class1 *theClass1 = [[Class1 alloc]init];
       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"It took you %d moves.",theClass1.movesCounter];
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

       [alert show];
       [alert release];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably post some code so we can check whats wrong.

Comment: It seems like you aren't initializing the property if it's returning 0.  All properties are defined as nil or 0 if they aren't initialized or set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a **new** instance of Class1 in your Class2 init method:

```
Class1 *theClass1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
```

This new instance is in addition to the one with the int you've been incrementing successfully, and as it's a fresh slice of memory, its value for movesCounter is still 0.  What you really want is a pointer to the specific copy of Class1 that you've been working with -- no alloc / init needed or desired.  Try making a property in Class2 that can hold your pointer to Class1:

```
#import "Class1.h"

@interface Class2 : NSObject {
    Class1 *myPointerToClass1;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Class1 *myPointerToClass1;
```

And of course @synthesize myPointerToClass1 in the .m of Class2.  Now that Class2 is ready to hold a pointer to Class1, you need simply to populate it.  In Class1, after the code that alloc's and init's the Class2 instance, use code like this:

```
myClass2.myPointerToClass1 = self;
```

Just to make sure I haven't forgotten anything I did all this using your code above and everything worked just fine for me.

---

**EDIT: original answer begins here, but is now irrelevant.....** 
You mention having defined the counter as a property, but have you also synthesized the instance variable in your implementation (.m) file?

```
@synthesize myCounter;
```

This will create the setter and getter methods automatically for you. Also, have you verified that the value is being incremented at all, perhaps with an NSLog statement in the viewcontroller?

```
NSLog(@"myCounter is currently equal to %d", myCounter); // assuming an int
```

If these basics are covered, maybe you could edit your question to include the code showing us more about how the misbehaving class is getting this pointer to the variable in the first place.

Comment: Yes I have it all set up. How should I access it from the other class?

Comment: ALright, I changed the synthesize statement but it still won't give me the right value. =/

Comment: On second thought, your real problem is that you're unintentionally creating a second instance of Class2, see my edited answer above.

Comment: I've set it up as you said, but how am I supposed to access the 'myPointerToClass1' property in the Class2?

Comment: Lucas - you could access any of the variables in your Class1 object from within your Class2 object at that point with code like: `int counterFromClass1 = myPointerToClass1.movesCounter;`

If this helps you (I'm pretty sure it does) would you kindly accept my answer?  Thanks and good luck.

Comment: It sounds crazy but I just can't get it right. I've set up this tiny app that illustrates exactly what I wanted to do:  [http://goo.gl/DGGXP] - it's just a view with a button that increments a counter and a label that displays the counter's value. There is also a second button that presents a modalView that should display the counter's value too, but it doesn't. I tried to set it up the way you instructed me to.

Comment: There are two relevant problems in your sample project.  First, you create a SecondView object every time the user increments the counter (no need to make a bunch of those, you're just leaking memory) - fix this by getting rid of the two lines of code relating to SecondView in your incrementCounter method.  You only need one copy of each of these two views, thus you only want the alloc/init statements to execute one time total per class.

Now in your goToOtherView method put in that code to set the pointer to this first class. `view.myPointerToClass1 = self;`

Answer (score 1):

In your header file you declare your iVar as

```
{
    int movesCounter;
}
```

but you synthesize the property with

```
@synthesize movesCounter = _movesCounter; // note the underscore
```

so the `movesCounter` iVar does not get connected to the `movesCounter` property. If you are updating just `movesCounter` instead of `self.movesCounter` or `_movesCounter` then external classes will not be able to see these changes.

Comment: I synthesized it just as shown above and it changed nothing.. I don't understand.

Comment: Oh, now I guess I see what you mean! I'll try it out :D

Comment: I understand what you said, but would exactly would I do it? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Remove the `{ int movesCounter; }` from your header file. If you get compiler errors/warnings, just change the `movesCounter`s in your methods into `self.movesCounter`.