# Accessing int value from another class

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

I am having trouble accessing an int property from another class. I know this question has been asked quite a few times however none of the solutions posted in previous questions seem to work. My knowledge in xcode is basic, and I am using this project to develop my skills.

The two classes I have are: HelloWorldLayer and ClassOne. Where ClassOne states the value of int. Both are Cocos2d CCLayer classes (probably not the best class to practice inter-class value access).

**ClassOne.h**

```
@interface ClassOne : CCLayer {
  int ageClass;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite)int ageClass;

@end
```

**ClassOne.m**

```
@implementation ClassOne
@synthesize ageClass = _ageClass;

-(id)init{
   if((self=[super init])){
     _ageClass = 10;

   }
 return self;
}

@end
```

**HelloWorldLayer.h**

```
#import "ClassOne.h"

@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <...> {
   ClassOne *agePointer;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign)ClassOne *agePointer;
+(CCScene*)scene;

@end
```

**HelloWorldLayer.m**

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ClassOne.h"

@implementation HelloWorldLayer
@synthesize agePointer = _agePointer;
+(CCScene*)scene...

 -(id)init{
   if((self=[super init])){
     _agePointer.ageClass = self;

   NSLog(@"ClassOne int = %@",_agePointer);

   }
 return self;
}

...
@end
```

**Output Result:**

```
"ClassOne int = (null)" 

or "0" if i use "%d" token and "int = x", where the line "int x =_agePointer.ageClass;"
is used.
```

The result I am after is for the HelloWorldLayer NSLog to display "10", the int value defined in ClassOne.

Any wisdom and corrections on my use of language is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does this line means "_agePointer.ageClass = self;" ageClass is an integer and you try to assign an object in it. I think it will work as : -(id)init{
   if((self=[super init])){
     _agePointer = [[ClassOne alloc] init];

   NSLog(@"ClassOne int = %d",_agePointer.ageClass);

   }
 return self;
}

Comment: I was using this question as a guide [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371125/accessing-a-value-of-a-classs-variable-from-another-objective-c). I was under the impression that that line assigns the value from "ageClass" to "_agePointer".

Comment: That solved it. Thanks Prateek, if you post that up as an answer I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Try This:

```
-(id)init
 { 
    if((self=[super init])){ 
       _agePointer = [[ClassOne alloc] init]; 
        NSLog(@"ClassOne int = %d",_agePointer.ageClass); 
     } 
  return self; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when outputting int, always use `%d` instead of `%@` in your NSLog.

Second of all, if you are expecting to output 10, you should've instantiated the class first in your `HelloWorldLayer.m`:

```
-(id)init{
   if (self = [super init]) {
   _agePointer = [[ClassOne alloc] init];

   NSLog(@"ClassOne int = %@",_agePointer);
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Enrico, initiating the class was definately required.