# How to access a variable in another class in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem when try to access a variable in a class. I'm a generate NSString in a AppDelegate.m and want to use this NSString in another class.m. I'm use "extern" in "AppDElegate.h" but my project dont build.

My code in AppDelegate.m is

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description] 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]   
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

My code in AppDelegate.h is

```
extern NSString *deviceTokenString;
```

And use in "AnotherClass.m" like this

```
- (void) sendEndPoint{
NSLog(@"Token device  login:%@",deviceTokenString);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `extern` in this case.  That should be reserved for truly static constants - they don't change value.  If you want to be able to access this via `AppDelegate.deviceTokenString` then you should use `static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a global variable, you could also store it using `NSUserDefaults`, which can be accessed from any class you want.

First you store it as follows:

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = // obtain your string here
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: deviceTokenString forKey: @"deviceTokenString"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then you can retrieve it using:

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"deviceTokenString"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `AppDelegate`s header into the file in which you want to reference your `deviceTokenString`. That will solve one problem.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

But the other problem you're having is that you cannot initialize `deviceTokenString` that way. Instead, you need to put that code somewhere else, such as in `application:didFinishLaunching:` or in your `AppDelegate`s `initialize` class method.

Global C variables can only be initialized with constants or `@"your string here"`.

Comment: ty for your answer. I import "AppDelegate.h" in my "anotherclass.m", but i dont have access to valor for "deviceTokenString", Initialize the variable before occupying and not even

Answer (score 0):

Already we had a answer this question.kindly :[Click Here](http://:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371125/accessing-a-value-of-a-classs-variable-from-another-objective-c)

Comment: your link is empty.